# Randomize the order of divs displayed and hidden using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I'm using this jquery code that I got from another post here to fade some divs in and out

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="feature-"]').hide(),
        i = 0;
    (function cycle() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(400, cycle);
        i = ++i % divs.length;
    })();
});    
</script>
```

to cycle through some divs, to make them fade in and fade out in a sort of haphazard slideshow.  I would like to randomize the displayed order on page load, for example right now it shows feature-1, then feature-2, then feature-3.  How can I get it to randomize that order, like sometimes onload will show feature-3, feature-1, feature-2, and sometimes it will show feature-2, feature-1, feature-3, etc etc.  I tried creating an array and then randomizing numbers between 1 and 10 and placing them in indices 0-9, but I couldn't get it to display at all after I tried.  Here's a jfiddle to show what it's doing.

http://jsfiddle.net/gthes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Math.Random()`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp

Example:
Random number from 1 to 6

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="feature-"]').hide(),
        i = 0,
        lastIndex=-1;
    (function cycle() {
         do{     
            i = Math.floor((Math.random()*6));       
         }while(i==lastIndex);

        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
            .delay(5000)
            .fadeOut(400, cycle);      

         lastIndex=i;

    })();
});
```

Comment: This was only doing 2, then I removed the +1 at the end of the math random, now it randomizes.  How can I keep it from repeating numbers in a row, such as 1 and then 1 again?

Comment: @Frits i answered first! XD

Comment: @DmitryKvochkin: Yes, but your initial answer was basically just "Use `Math.Random` (sic), which was of little value. This revised answer has value, other than oddly always assuming six divs...

Comment: .. and being off-by-one in the random number picker.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the answer, it works and I'm good with the assumed max, there's only a max of 10 divs ever anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="feature-"]').hide(), last_index = false;

    function get_random_index(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }

    function cycle() {
        var i;
        do {
            i = get_random_index(divs.length);
        } while (i === last_index);
        last_index = i;     
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400).delay(5000).fadeOut(400, cycle);
    }
    cycle();
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good comment, ammended the code, it now always picks a different one.

Comment: This keeps crashing jsfiddle, I'll try it live... edit: yeah, it stops displaying after the first div, and then it's just blank.